# Multi Color dataLabel in Bar Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I basically need to have formatted data values on chart that represent two different data sets. I want to show them in different colors. Here is what I did in chart options of highchart

```
plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                     formatter: function() {
                        return '<div class="orange">'+ this.y +' % '+ '</div> | '+
                            '<div class="brown">'+ this.point.name + ' % </div>';
                    }
                },
                pointWidth: 22
            }
        }
```

I see both the values However colors remains same.

Any clue how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can achieve multicolored datalabels.

Highcharts accepts HTML in formatter it then converts into an svg and then places it in a span element.

to make your stuff work set `useHTML: true`

this will render the html you us in the formatter. if you don't set this it will not take the HTML part as HTML. it simply renders the things mentioned inside html tags.

hope using useHTML will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter):

> A subset of HTML is supported. The HTML of the tooltip is parsed and
>   converted to SVG, therefore this isn't a complete HTML renderer. The
>   following tabs are supported: , , , , 
> , .
>   Spans can be styled with a style attribute, but only text-related CSS
>   that is shared with SVG is handled.

While this is talking about the `toolTip.formatter` it still applies to the `dataLabel.formatter`.